# How to show and hide a link list in Boostrap 3?

Tags: list, twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

I'm using Boostrap 3 and would like to show and hide the *options list* through the *Options:* link.

```
<ul class="side">
<li><a href="#">Options:</a></li>

<li>Option 1</li>
<li>Option 2</li>
<li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery for this.
Read jQuery documentation for info.
Here is the link for demo: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/